# Handshake failed due to unexpected packet format. WCF hosted in Windows Service

Tags: wcf, ssl, windows-services

I have a WCF that is hosted in a windows service.
My service runs on port 16000 and I am using basicHttpBinding in my app.config file. The service runs fine and I am able to connect to it when using http.
I later added SSL security to my service, with the following in my windows service code:

```
myServiceHost = New ServiceHost(type)     
myServiceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate (StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.Root, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "thumbprint with spaces")
```

The program compiled and the windows service is running without any errors.
I then bound the SSL certificate to my 16000 port using netsh and instructions in the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate.
However, when I am trying to add a reference to access it using https in the url, I am getting the exception: "Handshake failed due to unexpected packet format."
Here is my app.config file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
               <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour" name="myService_ClassLib.myService">             
            <endpoint address="myService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                contract="myService_ClassLib.ImyService" />            
         <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:16000" />                       
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Is there anything I am missing that's causing this error?

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: Is there an inner exception or is that the entirety of you error message? You might need to add a binding now that you are using https: 
`<bindings>
 <basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="HTTPSbasicBinding" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
   <security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
   </security>
  </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>`

Comment: That is the inner exception. The actual error message is:<br>

Comment: did you try adding the binding and assigning the binding name to your BindingConfiguration in the endpoint element? Are you able to browse the url to the service in a brower?

Comment: which account  you use to run windows service. we must ensure that the account could access the certificate.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-make-x-509-certificates-accessible-to-wcf
Do you have tried host the service in IIS?